# Pass a variable from views.py to .html

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I have a table which can store comment ratings. I'm trying to calculate the average of comment ratings and print it in my store.html file. But {{ average }} doesn't return any value.

What i've tried,

models.py

```
class MyComments(models.Model):

    TRUE = 'True'
    FALSE = 'False'
    
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (TRUE, 'yes'),
        (FALSE, 'no'),
    )
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='comments',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=200,blank=True)
    rate = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS_CHOICES,default=TRUE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject
```

views.py

```
def average_of_rates(request, product_id):
    comments = MyComments.objects.filter(product_id=product_id,status=MyComments.TRUE)
    
    rates = 0
    amount = 0
    
    for comment in comments:
        rates += comment.rate
        amount+=1
    
    average = rates/amount

    return render(request,'store/store.html',{
        'average': average,
    })
```

urls.py

```
 path('comments/<int:product_id>/', views.average_of_rates, name='average_of_rates'),
```

store.html

```
<p class = "font-extrabold text-lg"> {{ average }}</p>
```

I'm new to django btw. What's the mistake that i am doing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `len(comments) == 0`, then you get `ZeroDivisionError` and it would not be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am not getting any errors. {{ average }} not showing anything even if i change its value.

Comment: @henry-68 if you just changed the code, **restart the server**, and try loading the page again.

Comment: I restarted the server and the database, nothing seems to be changed. I don't know if i am passing the variable to the html right way. Kinda confused to be honest.

Comment: @henry-68 try step by step. Change `store.html` to `<p>test</p>`. Do you see `test` on that page? If not, then the template is not loaded properly. If yes, change to `def average_of_rates(request, product_id): return render(request,'store/store.html',{'average': 10})`. Do you see `10` on the page? What do the logs say? Does it say template loaded successfully? If possible, show all of your code in GitHub.

Comment: i checked all my codes from start to end as you mentioned and found the problem. i learned that my codes in view.py were mess because i wanted to combine some functions in one Class but couldn't do it properly. Now that i know the drill, it's all working.  (it took me almost a day to figure it out but it did worth). Thank you for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def average_of_rates(request, product_id):
    comments = MyComments.objects.filter(product_id=product_id,status=MyComments.TRUE)
 
    if not comments:
        return 0

    rates = 0
    amount = 0


    for comment in comments:
        rates += comment.rate
        amount+=1
    
    average = rates/amount

    return render(request,'store/store.html',{
        'average': average,
    })
```

Comment: Unfortunately issue still proceeds. I can't seem to return a value.